# Is there an project or mature model for event tracking in nlp?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, recurrent-neural-network, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I'm just getting started in nlp. Recently I have a project for news event extracting and tracking. The main task is extracting event(not limited to the ACE 2005 format) and finding relations within events such as temporal relation or casual relation from news text or title.

I did some research and found that mainstream method of event extraction is based on ACE2005 datasets and very little work about event tracking.

**so I want to know:**

1. Is there open source project or mature model about event extracting and tracking that I could refer to?
2. Maybe you could give me a direction which I'll work in

Thank you all guys!

Answer (score 0):

As of 2019 - No, there are no mature open source NLP event tracking solutions.

There are niche paid solutions (News and Finance).

Besides several PDF's explaining possible approaches there is [a post on medium](https://towardsdatascience.com/natural-language-processing-event-extraction-f20d634661d3) which included [(corrupt) code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rodrigosnader/medium-scraper/master/Document%20Classification%20-%20News%20Topics.ipynb#) but provided an outline.

If you are interesting in building one please let me know